# How do I fill the contents of a matrix using 9 other matrixes?

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

I am creating a sudoku game

I have 9 3x3 matrixes and a large 9x9 matrix. The methods I tried didn't work so please help me:

```
void matrix_full_creation()
 {
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {   
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
        
                matrix_full[i][j]==matrix1[i][j];
                matrix_full[i][j+3]=matrix2[i][j];
                matrix_full[i][j+6]=matrix3[i][j];
            
                matrix_full[i+3][j]=matrix4[i][j];
                matrix_full[i+3][j+3]=matrix5[i][j];
                matrix_full[i+3][j+3]=matrix6[i][j];

                matrix_full[i+6][j]=matrix7[i][j];
                matrix_full[i+6][j+3]=matrix8[i][j];
                matrix_full[i+6][j+6]=matrix9[i][j];
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Look for `==` in your code, and replace it with just `=`. And for matrix6 it should be `matrix_full[i+3][j+6]=matrix6[i][j];`, not `matrix_full[i+3][j+3]=matrix6[i][j];`. Except for those two typos, it looks good.

Comment: @Stef you are given no idea of the actual types involved, except they must be global. it looks horrible.

Comment: I think there is also a typo where `j+3` should be `j+6` on the `matrix6` line. Attention to detail is essential.

Comment: *"didn't work"* -- this is useless as a problem description. It covers everything from "I don't have a compiler" to "I accidentally created an AI that is trying to play a nice game of chess" (instead of Sudoku). Please be precise. What is the symptom? What did you observe, and what did you expect to observe? (This might be easier to do if you add output to your [mre].)

Answer (score 0):

- Given a submatrix index `n`, and a pair of indexes within that submatrix, i.e. row index `i` and column index `j`, and
- considering you want to place each submatrix at positions `(0,0)`, `(0,1)`..., `(3,3)` of the full matrix,
- you can walk each cell of each submatrix, and
- use the following formula to calculate the destination cell in the full matrix:

```cpp
matrix_full[3*(n / 3) + i][3*(n % 3) + j] = submatrix[i][j];
```

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/o9j5qY4Yh)

Answer (score -1):

Let's break your task into smaller pieces.
First, write a function that copies your small matrix into specific position

```
void Copy(int** small, int i, int j);
```

So if you pass 0, 0 for i, j... It should copy contents of small into top left 3x3 submatrix of the big 9x9 matrix.

When you complete this task, just run a for loop (similar to the one you already did)

```
int** bigMatrix; // assume we have it here

void Copy(int** small, int i, int j) {
    for(int ii = 0; ii < 3; ++ii) {
        for(int jj = 0; jj < 3; ++jj) {
            bigMatrix[i + ii][j + jj] = small[ii][jj];
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int smalls[3][3][3] = {...}; // assume we have 3x3 init here

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i += 3) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j += 3) {
            Copy(smalls[0], i, j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Good tip: divide and conquer!

Comment: This `int*** smalls = {...}` is not legal code, no matter what you replace the `...` with. You also have at least one typo in your `Copy` function.

Comment: Yeah, I was just quick editing... Mised that one. (Wrote the answer on mobile ) Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I have corrected your code. Try this:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {   
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
    
            matrix_full[i][j]=matrix1[i][j];
            matrix_full[i][j+3]=matrix2[i][j];
            matrix_full[i][j+6]=matrix3[i][j];
        
            matrix_full[i+3][j]=matrix4[i][j];
            matrix_full[i+3][j+3]=matrix5[i][j];
            matrix_full[i+3][j+6]=matrix6[i][j];

            matrix_full[i+6][j]=matrix7[i][j];
            matrix_full[i+6][j+3]=matrix8[i][j];
            matrix_full[i+6][j+6]=matrix9[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: _How_ does this fix it? Does it? I still see the `==`/`=` issue.

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed it. Try now.